# JQuery Mobile - On Click event of list item not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am using a simple JQuery Mobile page as follows:

```
<div data-role="page" id="myuploads">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="header" data-position="fixed">
         <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" id="myuploadlist">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I am running this javascript code to populate the list of the page, and apply an on click function. This takes the user to another page to show the image that has been uploaded. It does this through the ID of the list item, which is then stored in localstorage and used to populate the page.

```
 $("#myuploads").live("pageinit", function() {

//retrieve details from local storage (logged in)
var userid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userid"));

console.log(userid);

//serialise post data manually
var postData = 'userid=' + userid;

$('body').addClass('ui-loading');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: postData,
    url: 'MYURLREMOVED',
    success: function(data){
        $('body').removeClass('ui-loading');
        //alert("success");
        $('#myuploadlist').append('<li>Active</li>');

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('#myuploadlist').append('<li><a href="index.html#image" id="' + data[i].Details.File + '">Upload: ' + data[i].UploadID + ' - ' + data[i].Details.TotalViews + ' Views</a></li>');
        }
        $('#myuploadlist').listview('refresh');
    },
    error: function(){
        $('body').removeClass('ui-loading');
        //alert("failure");
        $('#myuploadlist').append('<li>Cannot Load Uploads</li>');
        $('#myuploadlist').listview('refresh');
    }
});

$('#myuploadlist').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var elementID = $(this).attr('id');
    $(document).on('click', '#'+elementID, function(event){
        if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
        {

            localStorage.setItem('selectedImage', elementID);
            //console.log("stored: " + localStorage.getItem('selectedImage'));
            //The below code is handled in a href when list is generated
            //$.mobile.changePage( $("userprofile"), "slide", true, true);
            event.handled = true;
        }
    });
});
```

});

This works, however only the first time. When I click back and click a new list item it still shows the previously displayed image. I know that the list IDs have been allocated correctly.

Is this the correct way of achieving what I am trying to do? And can anyway see the problem with my events? Thanks.

Comment: jQ and jQM versions used?

Comment: slightly older versions I think Omar, jquery mobile version 1.2.1 and jquery version 1.8.3